# Adobe PDF reader com component C# open on specific pagenumber

Tags: c#, pdf, com

I am using the Adobe FDF reader from the com components in C#. It opens the PDF file I want in my form but it opens on page number 1. Does anyone know if I can open it for example on page number 5?

Here is the code that I user:

```
pdfWiki.src = pdfWiki.src = "F:\\STAGE\\test.pdf";
```

Hope u could help me..

Thanks!

Comment: After looking at the properties of the element I found the solution:

            pdfWiki.src = pdfWiki.src = "F:\\STAGE\\test.pdf";
            pdfWiki.setCurrentPage(NUMBER);

Replace NUMBER for the pagenumber you want to visit!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pdfWiki.src = @"F:\\STAGE\\test.pdf";
pdfWiki.setCurrentPage(5);
```